# for loop sobre dicionário com listas para obter values

Tags: python, loop, dicionário

Olá.
Preciso criar uma variável para as keys 'chefe_projeto' e 'funcionarios' (esta contém 2 dicionários internos) onde o conteúdo seria o valor de "HorasProjeto".
Exemplo:
horas_chefe = 3500
horas_funcionario1 = 500
horas_funcionario2 = 1100

```
dicionario = {
'chefe_projeto': {
'Nome': 'Juan', 
'Idade': 28, 
'Experiência': ['Gestão', 'Finanças', 'Basesdedados'], 
'Residência': 'Madrid', 
'HorasProjeto': 3500}, 
'funcionarios': [{
                   'Nome': 'Elena', 
                   'Idade': 26, 
                   'Experiência': ['JavaScript', 'Python'], 
                   'Residência': 'Madrid', 
                   'HorasProjeto': 500},
                   {
                   'Nome': 'Luis', 
                   'Idade': 31, 
                   'Experiência': ['Django', 'Flask', 'Pyramid'], 
                   'Residência': 'Barcelona', 
                   'HorasProjeto': 1100}]
}
```

Sei que consigo criar as tais variáveis dessa forma:

```
horas_chefe = dicionario['chefe_projeto']['HorasProjeto']
```

mas, seria possível criar usando for loop?

Comment: Não entendi. Para que precisa do loop se `dicionario['chefe_projeto']['HorasProjeto']` tem um valor único?

Comment: seria para criar as variáveis do dicionario de funcionarios, onde tenho 2 dicionarios internos...

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma lista e preenchê-la com os valores de cada key "HorasProjeto", como segue:

*Colei seu dict no codigo e identei ele

```
thisdict = {
  'chefe_projeto': {
    'Nome': 'Juan', 
    'Idade': 28, 
    'Experiência': ['Gestão', 'Finanças', 'Basesdedados'], 
    'Residência': 'Madrid', 
    'HorasProjeto': 3500
  }, 
  'funcionarios': [
    {
        'Nome': 'Elena', 
        'Idade': 26, 
        'Experiência': ['JavaScript', 'Python'], 
        'Residência': 'Madrid', 
        'HorasProjeto': 500
    }, 
    {
        'Nome': 'Luis', 
        'Idade': 31, 
        'Experiência': ['Django', 'Flask', 'Pyramid'], 
        'Residência': 'Barcelona', 
        'HorasProjeto': 1100
    }
  ]
}

lista_horas = []

for x,y in thisdict.items():
    if type(y) is dict:
        lista_horas.append(y["HorasProjeto"])
    elif type(y) is list:
        for obj in y:
            lista_horas.append(obj["HorasProjeto"])

print(lista_horas)
```

Note que o método items() retorna um objeto dict_items, que contém os pares key/value do dicionário.
No loop for, a variável y representa o value de cada chave do dicionário thisdict, no caso, na primeira iteração, y representa os valores de 'chefe_projeto', e na segunda, os valores de 'funcionarios'.
A condição envolvendo type() serve pois o valor de 'funcionarios' é uma lista e o de 'chefe_projeto' e um dict.